# one shot kill function in SpriteKit

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

so I have the following code which kills an enemy with two shots from the player set up inside my `didBegin:contact`

```
var bulletCounter : Int = 0 //not declared inside didbegin just to be clear
nodesToRemove = [SKNode]() // not declared inside didbegin just to be clear       

if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet && body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy && (body2.node?.position.y)! < self.size.height{
                //if the bullet has hit the enemy
                bulletCounter += 1
                nodesToRemove.append(body1.node!) // remove bullet always
                switch bulletCounter {
                case 2:
                    nodesToRemove.append(body2.node!) // remove enemy
                    bulletCounter = 0
                    addScore()
                default:break
                }
```

followed by this

```
 override func didFinishUpdate()

{
    nodesToRemove.forEach(){$0.removeFromParent()}
    nodesToRemove = [SKNode]()
}
```

Now for my question, how can I create some sort of instant kill, 1 bullet to kill instead of 2, once the player has touched the shooterNode and make it last for 10 seconds or so?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Can you please elaborate some more about this elusive shooterNode that is not mentioned in your code?

Comment: The shooterNode is basically the skspritenode i created. It's the player. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'one-shot kill' is easy to implement, as there is no need to remember that the target has already been hit and to check this on each hit.

```
var bulletCounter : Int = 0 //not declared inside didbegin just to be clear
nodesToRemove = [SKNode]() // not declared inside didbegin just to be clear       

if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet &&
    body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy &&
    (body2.node?.position.y)! < self.size.height {
        //The bullet has hit the enemy, so remove both and update the score
    body1.node.removeFromParent()
    body2.node.removeFromParent()
    addScore()
    }
```

**EDIT Flexible solution using subclasses of SKSpriteNode**

OK - if we subclass bullet & enemy, we can have bullets that do more (or less damage), enemies with more or less health etc, all neatly tracked by the individual nodes.

Here is our new `bullet` class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Bullet: SKSpriteNode {

    var damageInflicted = 2 
    var health = 1  { // Possibility for some bullets to be stronger
       didSet {
             if health == 0 {
                removeFromParent()
             }
       }
}
```

and here is our new enemy:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    var health = 2 {
       didSet {
             if health == 0 {
                removeFromParent()
             }
       }
     var pointValue = 100  // Points for destroying
}
```

Your code now becomes:

```
if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet && body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy && (body2.node?.position.y)! < self.size.height{
     // The bullet has hit the enemy
     let enemyNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy ? contact.bodyA.node as! Enemy : contact.bodyB.node as! Enemy
     let bulletNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet ? contact.bodyA.node as! Bullet : contact.bodyB.node as! Bullet
     enemyNode.health -= bulletNode.damageInflicted
     bulletNode.health -= 1 
     addScore(enemyNode.pointValue)
     }
```

You can update individual bullets and enemies' `damageInflicted`, `health` and `scoreValues` as necessary.

Bullets and enemies will be initialised with :

```
let bullet = Bullet(imageNamed: "bullet")
```

and

```
let enemy = Enemy(imageNamed: "enemy1")
```

instead of:
     `let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")` etc.

Functions that return an SKNode and which often have `... as SKSpriteNode` will now have `as bullet` and `as enemy` instead.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the reply! But I already knew that this is the function for one shot kill. My question is, how can I call this code once the user has touched the player or a button? Kind of like a powerup that will last x amount of seconds to help you get more points then its back to double shots to kill.

Comment: Ah ok - sorry. You could set `playerpowerup: bool = true` to indicate that the powerup in in place, with an `SKAction` set to fire in 10 seconds to change it back to `false`. Then just check the bool in `didBegin`.

Comment: You could also subclass`SKSpriteNode` to create your `enemy`, add a `damaged: bool` or `timesHits: Int`property and use that to check if the enemy is damaged and should be removed, to avoid using your `bulletCounter`. It would then be easy to have enemies with different `numberOfHits` or to give specific enemies a health boost. You could also then have bullets that do more damage. (basically HP for enemies and damageInflicted for bullets). This sounds complicated but would be simple to implement.

Comment: It's times like these I wish I had a day off! Lol i will check this code as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: It's written mainly from memory, so let me know of any errors. Hopefully you can see how it makes you code simpler yet more flexible. The `removeFromParent` called when health = 0 could, of course, be replaced by a `performaDeathAnimation` function.